# Perl script to capture stderr and stdout of command executed in back-quotes

Tags: linux, perl

In the following command which I execute in a Perl script, how do I capture stderr?

```
my $output = `ssh login.com git clone --bare user@login.com:/nfs/repo/ /nfs/repo//4124/`;
if ($? ne '0')
{ 
    $stderr = $output;
    print $stderr;
}
else
{
    $stdout = $output;
    print $stdout;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
my $output = `ssh login.com git clone --bare user@login.com:/nfs/repo/ /nfs/repo//4124/ 2>&1`;
```

The `2>&1` at the end sends standard error to the same place as standard output, which is captured by the back-quotes.

Comment: Simple is best +1 (unless they actually need to be kept separate)

Comment: Thanks and also can it be redirected to a file also

Comment: @halkeye: If they need to be kept separate, then you have to work harder (or, more likely, just install and use the appropriate module where someone else has already done the harder work for you). But the script shown expects to treat the captured material as if it was all standard output if the program exits with a zero status (success) and as if it was all standard error if the program exits with a non-zero status, even though you can have non-error output even when the program fails and error output even when the program succeeds. This is nice and simple (unless perhaps you use a C shell).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yep, I fully agree, thats why I +1'd your answer.

Comment: Awesome! Short and sweet

Answer (score 6):

You can use [Capture::Tiny](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Capture::Tiny) to capture stdout, stderr or both merged.

Answer (score 3):

I'm personally a fan of the core module [IPC::Open3](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IPC%3a%3aOpen3), though the answer with 2>&1 will get both stderr and stdout in the same stream (and usually good enough). The following will keep them separated.
There are less low level solutions though.

```
use IPC::Open3
my $pid = open3(\*CHLD_IN, \*CHLD_OUT, \*CHLD_ERR, qw(ssh login.com git clone --bare user@login.com:/nfs/repo/ /nfs/repo//4124/));

waitpid( $pid, 0 );
my $child_exit_status = $? >> 8;
if (child_exit_status != 0)
{
    my $stderr = do { local $/; <CHLD_ERR> };
    print "Failed command because: $stderr\n";
}
my $stderr = do { local $/; <CHLD_OUT> };
print "command stdout: $stdout\n";
```

Answer (score 3):

```
use IPC::Run;
my $rcode = run [ "ssh", "login.com", "git", ... ],
    undef, \my $stdout, \my $stderr;

if ($rcode) {
  print $stderr, "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a frequently asked question: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq8.html#How-can-I-capture-STDERR-from-an-external-command%3f