# perl get ouput in a file along with STDERR and STDOUT

Tags: linux, perl

In the following command i want to wrtie the output to a file and also get the STDOUT,STDERR in output variable how can i do this

```
      my( $output) = `ssh login.com ls /tmp  > filename 2>&1`;
       print "\n=========$output============";
```

.

Comment: Have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9784064/1137055

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cat the file once its done.

```
my ($output) = `ssh login.com ls /tmp/ > filename 2>&1;cat filename`
print "\n=========$output============";
```

Edit: If keeping the exit code is important (and I think the answers in https://stackoverflow.com/a/9784064/1137055 are more complete and less hacky):

```
`ssh login.com ls /tmp/ > filename 2>&1`; # run command and output to a file
my $code = $?;
my $output = { local $/ = undef; open FILE, "file" or die "Couldn't open file: $!"; $string = <FILE>; close FILE; } # "slurp" the file in using perl
print "\n=========$output============$code========\n";
```

Or an even less ideal solution:

```
`ssh login.com ls /tmp/ > filename 2>&1`; # run command and output to a file
my $code = $?;
my $output = `cat filename` # read the file by shell
print "\n=========$output============$code========\n";
```

Comment: > redirects output to "filename", ; seperates commands, "cat filename" will output the newly saved file to stdout

Comment: But i relasied that in this case we do not get a exact return value,for ex: my ($output) = `ssh login.com ls /tmp11/ > filename 2>&1;cat filename`  the return status will be 0 still there is noo directory as /tmp11

Comment: For the third example this is the output Use of uninitialized value in print at ./temp2 line 1704. Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at ./temp2 line 1705.

Comment: In the third example stderr and stdout has an issue

Answer (score 2):

Isn't it more obvious to capture the result and then have Perl print it to a file?

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Capture::Tiny qw/capture_merged/;

open my $log, '>', 'filename';

$|++; #no buffering
my ($result, $status) = capture_merged { system 'ssh login.com ls /tmp' };

print "Result: $result";
print $log $result;
```

Comment: and since I believe this to be true, I think this question is just a dupe of the OPs question of an hour previous.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use one of the SSH::* modules from CPAN to do this. Or you can use the "tee" shell command.

```
my $output = `ssh login.com ls /tmp/ 2>&1 | tee filename`
```